# GCC issue with -Ofast?

Tags: c, gcc

I have a question about the latest GCC compilers (version >= 5) with this code:

```
#include <math.h>

void test_nan (
    const float * const __restrict__ in,
    const int n,
    char * const __restrict__ out )
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        out[i] = isnan(in[i]);
}
```

The assembly listing from GCC:

```
test_nan:
        movq    %rdx, %rdi
        testl   %esi, %esi
        jle     .L1
        movslq  %esi, %rdx
        xorl    %esi, %esi
        jmp     memset
.L1:
        ret
```

This looks like `memset(out, 0, n)`.
Why does GCC assume that no entries can be NaN with -Ofast ?
With the same compilation options, ICC does not show this issue.
With GCC, the issue goes away with "-O3".

Note that with "-O3", this query `gcc -c -Q -O3 --help=optimizers | egrep -i nan` gives `-fsignaling-nans [disabled]`.

I verified this both locally and on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:10,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:10,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:10,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:10),source:'%23include+%3Cmath.h%3E%0A%0Avoid+test_nan+(%0A++++const+float+*+const+__restrict__+in,%0A++++const+int+n,%0A++++char+*+const+__restrict__+out+)%0A%7B%0A++++for+(int+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+n%3B+%2B%2Bi)%0A++++++++out%5Bi%5D+%3D+isnan(in%5Bi%5D)%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C+source+%231',t:'0')),k:52.381350176962826,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cg101,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'1',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:'+-Ofast+-std%3Dc99',selection:(endColumn:12,endLineNumber:9,positionColumn:12,positionLineNumber:9,selectionStartColumn:12,selectionStartLineNumber:9,startColumn:12,startLineNumber:9),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+10.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C',t:'0')),k:47.61864982303719,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4), with the additional option "-std=c99".

Edit: by following the helpful answers below I can confirm that `-Ofast -std=c99 -fno-finite-math-only` properly addresses this issue.

Comment: That's exactly what `-Ofast` is documented to do.

Comment: And in general, virtually any time you catch yourself thinking it's a compiler bug, it isn't.

Comment: `man  gcc`, `/-Ofast`. Not terribly complicated.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. To be fair there's a tree of references to other options before you get to the details about NaN.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the GCC [Options That Control Optimizations](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) documentation.

`-Ofast` enables the following optimizations in addition to `-O3`:

> It turns on **-ffast-math**, -fallow-store-data-races and the Fortran-specific -fstack-arrays, unless -fmax-stack-var-size is specified, and -fno-protect-parens.

`-ffast-math` enables the following:

> -fno-math-errno, -funsafe-math-optimizations, **-ffinite-math-only**, -fno-rounding-math, -fno-signaling-nans, -fcx-limited-range and -fexcess-precision=fast.

`-ffinite-math-only` does the following:

> Allow optimizations for floating-point arithmetic that assume that arguments and results are **not NaNs** or +-Infs.

This allows it to assume that `isnan()` always returns `0`.

Answer (score 4):

[Barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62431609) explains why `-Ofast` causes the compiler to assume NaN never happens.  I have two things to add to this.

First, you said something about seeing `-fsignaling-nans [disabled]` in `--help=optimize` output.  *Signaling* NaNs are a subcategory of all NaN bit patterns.  The CPU will fire a floating-point exception when they are used (consult the architecture manual for exactly what "when they are used" means).  Normally people use only the other kind, *quiet* NaNs, because dealing with floating point exceptions is a pain; so, by default, GCC generates code that handles quiet NaNs (and ±Inf) but *not* signaling NaNs.  `isnan` is true for both quiet and signaling NaNs.  In short, `-fsignaling-nans` is a red herring; the option that directly controls the behavior you didn't like is `-ffinite-math-only`.

Second, if you were using `-Ofast` because you wanted this function to be vectorized, try `-O3 -march=native` instead.  Loop vectorization is enabled at `-O3`, and `-march=native` directs GCC to optimize for the full capabilities of the CPU it's running on. Without any `-march` switches, GCC will assume it can only use CPU features that are guaranteed to be available by the psABI; for x86-64 (as it appears you have), that's SSE2 but nothing later, which leaves out most of the vector capabilities.  On the computer I'm typing this on, `-O3 -march=native` produces code for your example function that's half the size *and* probably about four times as fast as `-O3` alone.